# how to add a missing dates and remove repeated dates in hourly time series

Tags: r, time-series

how to add a missing dates and  remove repeated dates  in hourly  time series . Missing date fill corresponding  dates with NA for rainfall.

The example time series like

```
               date  Rainfall(mm)
1970-01-05 00:00:00           1.0 
1970-01-05 01:00:00           1.0
1970-01-05 05:00:00           3.6
1970-01-05 06:00:00           3.6
1970-01-05 07:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 08:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 09:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 10:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 11:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `seq.POSIXt` to create a `data.frame` with no missing time steps (object `grid.`), and then use `merge` to combine with the observed `df` in my example.

This should solve your problem

```
# Create a sample data.frame missing every second observation.
df <- data.frame(date=seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00"), to=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 10:00:00"), by="2 hours"), rainfall=rnorm(6))
#Create a seq of times without anything missing
grid. <- data.frame(date=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00"), to=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 10:00:00"), by="1 hours"))
# Merge them together keeping all the values from grid.
dat. <- merge(grid., df, by="date", all.x=TRUE)
```

To remove duplicated values you can either look for them and remove them using the `duplicated` function.

```
# The ! means the reverse logic. Therefore TRUE becomes FALSE.
dup_index <- !duplicated(dat.[,1])
# Now re-create the dat. object with only non-duplicated rows.
dat. <- dat.[dup_index,]
```

The other way to do it is to use the `aggregate` function. This could be useful if you have duplicates which are really two different observations and therefore you want the mean of the two, using;

```
dat. <- aggregate(dat.[,2], by=list(dat[,1]), FUN=mean)
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

FAQ #13 in the the [zoo FAQ vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-faq.pdf) addresses the part about filling time series.  The `aggregate` argument in `read.zoo` handles the duplicates.  In this case we average them but we could have taken other action such as using `FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)`.  We use [chron](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/index.html) date/times here to avoid time zone problems (see [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf)) but we could have used POSIXct if time zones were relevant -- they seem not since they are not in the input.

```
Lines <- "date  Rainfall(mm)
1970-01-05 00:00:00           1.0 
1970-01-05 01:00:00           1.0
1970-01-05 05:00:00           3.6
1970-01-05 06:00:00           3.6
1970-01-05 07:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 08:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 09:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 10:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 11:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2
1970-01-05 13:00:00           2.2"

library(zoo)
library(chron)

asChron <- function(d, t) as.chron(paste(d, t))
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, skip = 1, index = 1:2, FUN = asChron, agg = mean)
merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/24))) # as in FAQ
```

If the data comes from a file replace `text = Lines` with something like `file = "myfile.dat"` .