# R Issue adding NA values for missing rows using data frames

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, missing-data

Thanks in advance for any help that is provided.

Long story short: I am working with hourly time series data from a measurement device (exported from SQL then imported in to R in order to properly format the date time ) - the time series contains missing data, sometimes in groups, and I need to locate these missing rows/indices and insert a new row for each instance that holds an `NA` value.

**Related Questions that did not solve my problem:**

[how to insert missing observations on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003819/how-to-insert-missing-observations-on-a-data-frame)

[Adding row to a data frame with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045681/adding-row-to-a-data-frame-with-missing-values)

**Problem Data**

The dataset that I am working with in this case is fairly large and varies depending on the measurement device I select.  As a test case, I have one time series that contains 17469 hourly observations.  I located a small section of the dataset that may be used for testing purposes.  Here it is:

```
> snip
                   date Reading
408 2015-12-15 00:00:00    4.40
409 2015-12-14 23:00:00    4.62
410 2015-12-14 22:00:00    4.61
411 2015-12-14 21:00:00    6.15
412 2015-12-14 20:00:00    6.06
413 2015-12-14 19:00:00    7.04
414 2015-12-14 18:00:00    8.57
415 2015-12-14 11:00:00    4.12
416 2015-12-14 10:00:00    3.73
```

We can see that observations are missing for 2015-12-14 12:00:00 to 2015-12-14 17:00:00.  I would like to first locate then populate the time series with these date times and input `NA` for the Reading column in these positions.  I would also like to return the indices that are missing in an additional vector.

How can this be done?

So far I have tried the following code (as suggested here, [how to add a missing dates and remove repeated dates in hourly time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599341/how-to-add-a-missing-dates-and-remove-repeated-dates-in-hourly-time-series)), but all I end up with is `NA` values when I perform the `merge` function and still need to identify where the missing indices are located.

Here is the result:

```
> grid = data.frame(date=seq.POSIXt(min(snip[,1]), to=max(snip[,1]), by="1 hours"));
> dat = merge(grid, snip, by="date", all.x=TRUE)
> dat
                  date Reading
1  2015-12-14 10:00:00      NA
2  2015-12-14 11:00:00      NA
3  2015-12-14 12:00:00      NA
4  2015-12-14 13:00:00      NA
5  2015-12-14 14:00:00      NA
6  2015-12-14 15:00:00      NA
7  2015-12-14 16:00:00      NA
8  2015-12-14 17:00:00      NA
9  2015-12-14 18:00:00      NA
10 2015-12-14 19:00:00      NA
11 2015-12-14 20:00:00      NA
12 2015-12-14 21:00:00      NA
13 2015-12-14 22:00:00      NA
14 2015-12-14 23:00:00      NA
15 2015-12-15 00:00:00      NA
```

What am I missing here?  Is it because `grid` and `snip$date` are in reverse order?  For additional information here is what the date time format looks like (in case this is from where my issue stems):

```
> snip[2,1]
[1] "2015-12-14 23:00:00 GMT"
```

The result of the dput(snip) command is as follows (thanks for the suggestion @42):

```
> dput(snip)
structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 11L, 10L), mday = c(15L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), yday = c(348L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L
), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Reading = c(4.4, 
4.62, 4.61, 6.15, 6.06, 7.04, 8.57, 4.12, 3.73)), .Names = c("date", 
"Reading"), row.names = 408:416, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: POSIXct values are numeric and not fully displayed with the print method. We would need to see `dput(snip)` to have any chance of know what the underlying values actually were. You could merge on their formatted (text) values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I was able to do it with some help from na.locf documentation. Does it help?

```
dat<- dget("yoursample")
require(xts)
datxts<- as.xts(dat[,-1],order.by = dat$date,frequency = 24)
tzn<-tzone(datxts)
g<- seq(start(datxts), end(datxts), "hour")
gxts<- xts(rep(NA,length(g)),order.by = as.POSIXct(g), tzone = tzn)

merge(datxts,gxts,all = T)$datxts
```

Edit: And also, your method works if you add a column of NA's to generated dataframe

```
dates=seq.POSIXt(min(snip[,1]), to=max(snip[,1]), by="1 hours")
grid = data.frame(date=dates,dummydata=rep(NA,length(dates)));
dat = merge(grid, snip, by="date", all=T)
```

Comment: beautiful, your first solution works very nicely.  However, the second solution simply appends an `NA` value for each date time in the original list, while it places `NA` in the missing rows, it also populates an `NA` for available observations.

Comment: is there a simple way to create a vector of the missing observations, perhaps by doing a set difference (sorry, I work primarily in MATLAB) on the dates contained in `datxts` and `gxts`?

Comment: The column dat$reading in the second one should be the same as the first answer.. are you getting any warnings regarding mismatching timezones?  And the second question-- you just want dates for which data is missing, right?

Comment: Sorry, here's the rest of it , to get the missing times : `as.POSIXct(setdiff(g, dat$date), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")` ..There may be a shorter way though..

Comment: first comment: I do not receive any errors, `dat` turns into a 25x3 data frame, appending `NA` in the `$Reading` column for dates that are missing as well as for those dates where observations are already existing.  It should be 15x3 with `NA` only present on those dates with missing observations

Comment: second comment: when I enter ` miss=as.POSIXct(setdiff(g, dat$date), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")` it simply replicates what is in `g` i.e. it does not separate the missing dates from those that are available.

Comment: to get the missing date times I found a solution using the `lubridate` package.  Here's the solution: first apply `requiire(lubridate`, then `gl = ymd_hms(g, tz = "GMT")`, then `dl = ymd_hms(dat$date, tz = "GMT")`, and finally `as.POSIXct(setdiff(gl, dl), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT");`.

Comment: Great .   Happy it's working well for you now. I do think there was/is some issue with the timezone that made the two sets of time different from each other.